How to use django/jinja tags to extend an html with a javascript snippet from another .js file
I am developing a django app.
There is a file templates/index.html file having some javascript snippets at its footer, such as
...

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- load jquery. I put this after leaflet -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- import a library leaflet.browser.print from local folder lib placed  in the staticfiles folder -->
<script src="{% static './lib/leaflet.browser.print.min.js' %}"></script>

There is also a file templates/publish_layers_in_html_page.html which contains a javascript snippet using jinja tags, the content is the following
<script> 
 
var overlayMaps = {};

// Shapefile wms
{% for s in shp %}
var {{ s.name }} = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', {
    layers: '{{s.name}}',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
})
overlayMaps['{{ s.name }}'] = {{ s.name }}

{% endfor %}

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false, position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map)

</script>

Is it possible to use django tag {% extends %} to insert this javascript snippet into the index.html file?
I have tryed to change the two files as follows, but with no success.
index.html
...

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- load jquery. I put this after leaflet -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- import a library leaflet.browser.print from local folder lib placed  in the staticfiles folder -->
<script src="{% static './lib/leaflet.browser.print.min.js' %}"></script>

{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

publish_layers_in_html_page.html
 {% extends "index.html" %}

 {% block scripts %}

<script> 
 
var overlayMaps = {};

// Shapefile wms
{% for s in shp %}
var {{ s.name }} = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', {
    layers: '{{s.name}}',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
})
overlayMaps['{{ s.name }}'] = {{ s.name }}

{% endfor %}

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false, position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map)

</script>

{% endblock %}

I have also tested that if I insert the javascript snippet at the end of index.html, the code operates correctly.

I do not know anything about jinja but it should be possible to add javascript into the index.html page with {% extends %}

This isn't related to your question but that rendering into JavaScript isn't something you should be doing. By doing that you're making your site vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS). Writing JavaScript dynamically like that is rarely a good idea and you should avoid that unless you really know what you're doing. See this page for examples how it can be dangerous to do what you're doing (Disclosure: I've written that specific article on that site)

You're doing reverse extension. What you want is publish_layers_in_html_page's js code inside index.html, But you've included index.html in publish_layers_in_html_page. Now when you do this what actually happens is the publish_layers_in_html_page template can access index.html's code, but not vice versa.
Updated code:
index.html
</body>

</html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- load jquery. I put this after leaflet -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- import a library leaflet.browser.print from local folder lib placed  in the staticfiles folder -->
<script src="{% static './lib/leaflet.browser.print.min.js' %}"></script>

{% include "publish_layers_in_html_page.html" %}

publish_layers_in_html_page.html
<script> 
 
var overlayMaps = {};

// Shapefile wms
{% for s in shp %}
var {{ s.name }} = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', {
    layers: '{{s.name}}',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
})
overlayMaps['{{ s.name }}'] = {{ s.name }}

{% endfor %}

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false, position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map)

</script>


It's funny how clear things can become counter-intuitive.
